# Passing variables in python to another web platform

Tags: python, rest

I have a code which requires to pass the latency, upspeed, dlspeed to another web site to display. Right now the code is as below

```
import datetime
import os
import sys
import shutil
import webbrowser
import tempfile
import subprocess
import json
import urllib.request
import statistics
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors

IPERF3_WIN_PATH = "data/iperf3.exe"
HTML_TEMPLATE_PATH = "data/template.html"

IPERF3_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
RESULT_UPLOAD_URL = "UPLOAD URL"
RESULT_VIEW_URL = "VIEW URL"

def resource_path(relative_path):
""" Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller
    This is to get a path which will work with pyinstaller
"""
try:
    # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in
    # _MEIPASS
    base_path = sys._MEIPASS
except Exception:
    base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

def ping(ip, tries):
""" Ping "ip" using the windows ping commmand
    Return the average ping as a int
"""
res = 0
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(
        ["ping", "-n", str(tries), ip]).decode("utf-8")
    res = int(output.split(" = ")[-1].split("ms")[0])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    input("Press Enter to Continue...")
    sys.exit("Error while trying to ping the server, exiting")
else:
    return res

def copyIperf3Exec():
""" On OSX :
    Copy the iperf3 binary to a tmp file,
    make it executable and return his path
    This is to avoid many bundle related problems
    On Windows, just return the package path """
return resource_path(IPERF3_WIN_PATH)


def get_iperf3_download():
""" Return the output of the iperf3 cli as a python dict """
ipf3_tmp = copyIperf3Exec()
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output([ipf3_tmp,
                                      "-c", IPERF3_HOST,
                                      "-J",
                                      "-P", "16",
                                      "-w", "710000",
                                      "-R"])
    res_string = output.decode("utf-8")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    input("Press Enter to Continue...")
    sys.exit("Problem while doing the test, please try again later")
else:
    return json.loads(res_string)


def get_iperf3_upload():
""" Return the output of the iperf3 cli as a python dict """
ipf3_tmp = copyIperf3Exec()
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output([ipf3_tmp,
                                      "-c", IPERF3_HOST,
                                      "-J",
                                      "-P", "10",
                                      "-w", "710000"])
    res_string = output.decode("utf-8")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    input("Press Enter to Continue...")
    sys.exit("Error while doing the upload test, please try again later")
else:
    return json.loads(res_string)


def get_userinfos():
""" Get the 3 informations to be presented to the user
( ip, upload speed, download speed )
Return a Dictionary
"""

show_start_msg(0)  # 0% Progress bar
avg_latency = ping(IPERF3_HOST, 5)
u_json = get_iperf3_upload()

show_start_msg(1)  # 40%
d_json = get_iperf3_download()

show_start_msg(2)  # 80%
ip = getip_apify()

u_bits_per_second = u_json['end']['sum_received']['bits_per_second']
d_bits_per_second = d_json['end']['sum_received']['bits_per_second']

u_testtime = u_json['end']['sum_received']['seconds']
d_testtime = d_json['end']['sum_received']['seconds']

u_testdate = u_json["start"]["timestamp"]["timesecs"]
d_testdate = d_json["start"]["timestamp"]["timesecs"]

res = {
    'ip': ip,
    'latency': avg_latency,
    'upspeed': u_bits_per_second,
    'dlspeed': d_bits_per_second,
    'upspeedtime': u_testtime,
    'dlspeedtime': d_testtime,
    'upspeeddate': u_testdate,
    'dlspeeddate': d_testdate
}

return res


def sendToDB(infos):
# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                             user='testclient',
                             password='password',
                             db='speed',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        def stp_date(stp):
            return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stp).strftime(
                '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        sql = ("INSERT INTO `speedlog`"
               "(`externalIP`, `uploadspeed`, `uploadspeedtime`,"
               "`uploadspeeddate`, `downloadspeed`, `downloadspeedtime`,"
               "`downloadspeeddate`, `latency`)"
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
        cursor.execute(sql,
                       (infos["ip"],
                        str(int(infos["upspeed"])),
                        str("{0:.2f}".format(infos["upspeedtime"])),
                        stp_date(infos["upspeeddate"]),
                        str(int(infos["dlspeed"])),
                        str("{0:.2f}".format(infos["dlspeedtime"])),
                        stp_date(infos["dlspeeddate"]),
                        str(int(infos["latency"]))))

    # connection is not autocommit by
    # default. So you must commit to save
    # your changes.
    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
    return


def getip_apify():
res = urllib.request.urlopen("http://api.ipify.org")
raw_ip = res.read()
return raw_ip.decode('utf-8')


def prepare_template(templatePath, infos):
""" Load an html located at templatePath and replace the necessary text
with the associated values from the iPerf3 infos
Return a string
"""
f_template = open(templatePath)
s_template = f_template.read()
f_template.close()
mod_template = s_template.replace("avglatency", str(int(infos['latency'])))
mod_template = mod_template.replace(
    "upspeed", str("{0:.3f}".format(infos['upspeed']/(1000*1000*1000))))
mod_template = mod_template.replace(
    "dlspeed", str("{0:.3f}".format(infos['dlspeed']/(1000*1000*1000))))
return mod_template


def str_to_tempHtml(str):
""" Write "str" in an .html temporary file
And return his path
"""
data = bytes(str, "utf-8")
tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".html", delete=False)
tmp.write(data)
tmp.flush()
return tmp.name


def show_start_msg(progress):
if sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
    unused = os.system('clear')
elif sys.platform.startswith('win32'):
    unused = os.system('cls')
print("="*70)
print("Speed Testing for 10G Network \n")
print("Powered by iPerf3")
print("="*70)
if progress == -1:
    input("Press Enter to Continue...\n")
    return
else:
    print("Press Enter to Continue...\n")
    print("Testing in progress")
    if progress == 0:
        print("[" + " "*68 + "]" + " 0%")
    elif progress == 1:
        print("[" + "#" * 27 + " " * 41 + "]" + " 40%")
    elif progress == 2:
        print("[" + "#" * 54 + " " * 14 + "]" + " 80%")
    elif progress == 3:
        print("[" + "#"*68 + "]" + " 100%")
        print("Completed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
show_start_msg(-1)
infos = get_userinfos()
sendToDB(infos)
show_start_msg(3)  # 100% Complete
data = { "key":"Jasdkjfhsda349*lio34sdfFdslaPisdf",
         "download":"2048000",
         "upload":"2048000",
         "latency":"10"}
req = urllib.request.Request(RESULT_UPLOAD_URL, json.dumps(data).encode(
    'ascii'))
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('ascii')
resp = resp.replace('\'', '"')
webbrowser.open(RESULT_VIEW_URL.format(json.loads(resp)['test_id']))
input("Press Enter to Continue...")
```

My `latency`, `upspeed` and `dlspeed` variables are stored as `infos`, and later sent over to the DB for recording via `sendtoDB(infos)`.

The next part is to also pass these sets of variables to another web using `RESTful`, which in the data, the first attribute `"key"` is the REST key for authentication, followed by the rest of the values like `latency`, `downloadspeed` and `uploadspeed`. However, you can see that in the data, all the 3 variables are hard-coded value instead of the values derived from the test, which is `latency`, `upspeed`and `dlspeed`.

How can I modify the code to get these attributes instead of the hardcoded ones?

Comment: I'm confused. You seem to have a Flask app, but no routes. And I'm not sure I understand the need for the custom `prepare_template` method. What's wrong with `render`?

Comment: The code does not have Flask, it is just being modified by the moderator. I would like to know, in the data (), how do I add in the values from latency, upspeed and dlspeed, instead of the hard coded value of 20480000.

Comment: Then what does the line that says `app = Flask(__name__)` do,  hmm? And to not use hard coded values, you should try to get them from somewhere else (like a file or a database), but it isn't clear in your question where else you have those values, so I'm not sure what you want other than hard coded values

Comment: Basically, the below 2 lines are not part of the code:

Comment: Basically, the below 2 lines are not part of the code:
# Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

In the below code:
data = { "key":"jlkjsdfd98580934349*lio34sdfFdslaPisdf",
             "download":"2048000",
             "upload":"2048000",
             "latency":"10"}
If you noticed, the data are attributes which consist of "key", "download","upload" and "latency", and the their values are "jlkjsdfd..", "2048000", "2048000" and "10".

Instead of using the hard coded value of "2048000", how can I use the variable of "dlspeed","upspeed" and "latency" from the earlier lines within the code.

Comment: I do not see variables with those names in your code. I see you replacing those strings in your template with some values.

Comment: What is contents of `infos`? You replace your hard coded values with whatever is inside of that...

Comment: Just updated the full code. Hopefully it will much clearer for you now. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please edit again with a [mcve]. I don't see the need for most of what you added if all you wanted was to replace some hard-coded values with some values from a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a method that returns this dictionary...

```
res = {
    'ip': ip,
    'latency': avg_latency,
    'upspeed': u_bits_per_second,
    'dlspeed': d_bits_per_second,
    'upspeedtime': u_testtime,
    'dlspeedtime': d_testtime,
    'upspeeddate': u_testdate,
    'dlspeeddate': d_testdate
}
```

And it is called `infos`, so use it

```
data = { "key":"xxxxxxxx",
     "download":infos['dlspeed']
     "upload":infos['upspeed'], 
     "latency":infos['latency']}
```